# Orange Canvas / python script / interpn

Tags: python, interpolation, orange

I'm trying to create a python script widget in Orange canvas, but it is difficult to find an effective example:

What I want to do is:
1) I want to create a learner based on scipy.interpolate.interpn (or other interp, this is to get an example)
2) the training dataset comes from an orange table (with target defined)
3) the output result is the same as existing learners, for example KNN

I tried to learn from existing widgets like the KNN one, but when I copy past the code in the script, nothing happens.

any idea on how to proceed ?

here is the code I've put in the script:

```
from Orange.data import Domain, Table
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

# 1 data generation
train_data = in_datas[0].copy()
data2predict_data = in_datas[1].copy()

print('step_1')

xtrain = train_data[:,0]
xtrain = np.reshape(xtrain,len(xtrain))

xtrain = np.array(xtrain)
xtrain = xtrain.T

ytrain = np.array(train_data[:,1])
ytrain = np.reshape(ytrain,len(ytrain))

# 2 learning
f = interp1d(xtrain, ytrain)
print('step_2')

# 3 predicting
xnew = data2predict_data[:,0]
xnew = np.reshape(xnew,len(xnew))  
xnew = np.array(xnew)
xnew = xnew.T

ynew = f(xnew)
print('step_3')

out_data = Table(np.reshape(ynew,[len(ynew),1]))
```

As you cas see with my code, I'm using 2 dataset as input during the process. What I would like to do is to have a learning phase. And when I want, I can plug a new dataset on it to predict. How to do that ?

Being able to detect automatically the target would be fine...

Comment: if you means `Orange3` then maybe you should ask authors:  https://orange.biolab.si/

Comment: Please provide a code example so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: The documentation for creating Orange python windows is not great, unfortunately

Comment: You should start with a more simple example by following the tutorial here:
https://docs.biolab.si//3/visual-programming/widgets/data/pythonscript.html